# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed. on connecting IMAP store with valid credentials

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I have an application that connects to IMAP store via Java Mail API (v1.4.7) to fetch emails on regular intervals(30 seconds in my case). I am able to connect regularly, fetch emails and close the connection but after a while (sometimes days, sometimes weeks) I get AuthenticationFailedException. Next, on few retries, I am again able to connect and fetch emails. Later, even this stopped working on retry attempts. It would work only if there's no connection made to the server for 5 minutes or so. So, an application stop and start is required causing too many down times. Is it the exchange server or the javamail API, I am not sure. Please help me with the causes of authenticationfailedexception with valid credentials provided.

Comment: Server software often has spam protection: eg, too many connections from one source address or too frequent connections. Polling every thirty seconds is ridiculous. Do you cache connections? Use IDLE? You also have to accept the fact that occasionally servers will not be able to log you in due to their own problems (can't connect to their authentication servers) and should implement an exponential backoff.